# Prove infinite markov reward process converges

Tags: proof-writing, markov-process

The following question is obtained from Stanford CS234 Lecture 2 notes, Excercise 3.7

Let $r_i$ denote the reward obtained from transition $s_i\rightarrow s_{i+1}$.
Furthermore, the return $G_t$ of a Markov reward process is defined as the discounted sum of rewards starting at time $t$ up to the horizon $H$, and is given by the following mathematical formula $G_t=\sum_{i=t}^{H-1}\gamma^{i-t}r_i, \forall0\leq t\leq H-1$.

Consider an infinite horizon Markov reward process, with bounded rewards, i.e. $\exists M \in (0,\infty), \forall i,|r_i|\leq M $ , and $\gamma<1$. Prove that the return for any episode $G_t$ as defined above converges to a finite limit. The plan  is to consider the partial sum $S_N=\sum_{i=t}^{N}\gamma^{i-t}r_i$ and show that {$S_N$} is a Cauchy sequence. I'm trying to show that the sequence is Cauchy, but I can't seem to find a viable upper bound for $|S_n-S_m|$.

Here is my attempt so far:

For any $n,m\geq t$,

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
|S_n-S_m| & = |\sum_{i=t}^{n} \gamma^{i-t}r_i - \sum_{i=t}^{m} \gamma^{i-t}r_i| \\
 & \leq |\sum_{i=t}^{n} \gamma^{i-t}r_i| + |\sum_{i=t}^{m} \gamma^{i-t}r_i|\\ 
 & \leq \frac{M}{1-\gamma}(1-\gamma^{n-t+1}) + \frac{M}{1-\gamma}(1-\gamma^{m-t+1}) \\ 
& = \frac{M}{1-\gamma}(2-\gamma^{n-t+1}-\gamma^{m-t+1}) \\
& = ...
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The first inequality is justified by triangle inequality.

Second inequality is justified because $|G_t|$ becomes a geometric series.

Would sincerely appreciate any hint on how I could continue from here :)

Follow up from @sudeep5221's comment:

For $n > m \geq t,$

\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\begin{split}
|S_n-S_m| & = |\sum_{i=t}^{n} \gamma^{i-t}r_i - \sum_{i=t}^{m} \gamma^{i-t}r_i| \\
 & = |\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} \gamma^{i-t}r_i|\\
 & \leq \frac{M}{1-\gamma}\gamma^{m+1-t}(1-\gamma^{n-m-1})\\
 & \leq \frac{M}{1-\gamma}\gamma^{m+1-t} \\
 & < ...
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: In the second step, instead of using triangle inequality, write it as $\displaystyle | \sum_{i = m+1}^n \gamma^{i - t} r_i |$. Now use the geometric sum and proceed.
Also, it says that $G_t$ converges to a limit. Does it mean as $H \to \infty$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 thanks for the reply! 1. I've tried to use your suggestion and what I've arrived at is shown in the original post. What I'm trying to do is to find an expression in terms of $t$ so that I can get a lower bound for $t$ in terms of $\epsilon, M, \gamma$. However, I can't get a viable expression using your suggestion. 2. Since it's mentioned that we are considering a *infinite horizon* Markov reward process, so I would presume that it means $H\rightarrow \infty$.